# Link to next page (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

At the moment I have my posts linking directly to the next one but need a solution to do the same with pages from the first level.

I thought it would be something similar to the code I'm already using.

Linking posts code:

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried out the "Next Page, Not Next Post" Wordpress plugin?

> Easily create navigation to sibling pages. Similar to next_post_link() and previous_post_link() but for pages. (...) Next Page, Not Next Post is a very simple plugin that creates navigation between sibling pages.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/next-page-not-next-post/

Comment: would like to avoid plugins if possible

Comment: You could look into how the plugin works. If it's a simple hack, it shouldn't be too difficult to implement that functionality in your code.